# Task Assignment System using AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to build a  system that has a no. of task submitted by a different business user. Then I want to assign the task to someone in the organization. Below is the example of task list:

[image]

Below is the roles that the system should have. HOD will be able to view each record submitted by user. HOD will approve the task before Managers can view it and assign the task to counsiles.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me whether Google AppMaker capable of doing it or not? How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible but you need to write this logic by yourself in Appscript (Client/Server) side. Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/travel-approval/)

Comment: I already go through the template but don't really get it how to actually assign a specific privilege to a certain user. For example how to assign task no 2. to user "Counsile"